# Tensorflow LSTM throws ValueError: Shape () must have rank at least 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

When attempting to run, the following exception (ValueError) is thrown

```
ValueError: Shape () must have rank at least 2
```

This is being thrown against the following line:

```
states_series, current_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, inputs_series, init_state)
```

Where `cell` is defined here:

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
```

Looking at the rules for [RNN](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py) and [Tesor_shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/resources/dims_types), I can see that this is some kind of Tensor dimension shape issue.  From what I can tell, it's failing to see `BasicLSTMCell` as a rank 2 matrix?

Full Error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/glennhealy/PycharmProjects/firstRNNTest/LSTM-RNN.py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
  return f(*args, **kwds)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/glennhealy/PycharmProjects/firstRNNTest/LSTM-RNN.py", line 42, in <module>
    states_series, current_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, inputs_series, init_state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 1181, in static_rnn
    input_shape = first_input.get_shape().with_rank_at_least(2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 670, in with_rank_at_least
    raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank at least %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape () must have rank at least 2

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code:

```
state_size = 4
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
states_series, current_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, inputs_series, init_state)
```

Tensorflow 1.2.1 
Python 3.6 
NumPy

Updating with further information:

Considering the advice given by @Maxim I can see that the issue is my `input_series` and this is causing the shape issue, however, I can't seem to get my head around his advice.

Some more information to help with things see if I can understand how to fix this:

Would the following be a replacement for my placeholders of BatchY and BatchX??

```
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_steps, n_inputs])
X_seqs = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(X, perm=[1, 0, 2]))
basic_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons)
output_seqs, states = tf.nn.static_rnn(basic_cell, X_seqs,         dtype=tf.float32)
```

So, do I have to make changes to the following to reflect the syntax of the following?

```
batchX_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size,      truncated_backprop_length])
batchY_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size,    truncated_backprop_length])

#unpacking the columns:
labels_series = tf.unstack(batchY_placeholder, axis=1)
inputs_series = tf.split(1, truncated_backprop_length, batchX_placeholder)

#Forward pass
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
states_series, current_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, inputs_series, init_state)

losses = [tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels) for logits, labels in zip(logits_series,labels_series)]
total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
```

Comment: Could it be the input_series??

inputs_series = tf.split(1, truncated_backprop_length, batchX_placeholder)
labels_series = tf.unstack(batchY_placeholder, axis=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the problem is with `inputs_series`. According to the error, it's a tensor with shape `()`, i.e., just a number.

From [`tf.nn.static_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn) documentation:

> `inputs`: A length `T` list of inputs, each a Tensor of shape `[batch_size, input_size]`, or a nested tuple of such elements.

In most cases, you want `inputs` to be `[seq_length, None, input_size]`, where:

- `seq_length` is the sequence length, or the number of LSTM cells.
- `None` stands for the batch size (any).
- `input_size` is the number of features per cell.

So make sure your placeholders (and thus `inputs_series`, which is transformed from them) has the appropriate shape. Example:

```py
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_steps, n_inputs])
X_seqs = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(X, perm=[1, 0, 2]))
basic_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons)
output_seqs, states = tf.nn.static_rnn(basic_cell, X_seqs, dtype=tf.float32)
```

**Update:**

This is the wrong way to split the tensor:

```py
# WRONG!
inputs_series = tf.split(1, truncated_backprop_length, batchX_placeholder)
```

You should do it like this (note the order of arguments):

```py
inputs_series = tf.split(batchX_placeholder, truncated_backprop_length, axis=1)
```

Comment: So, you're saying I need to modify the Input_Series to reflect your example? 

Given, that:

`X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_steps, n_inputs])
X_seqs = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(X, perm=[1, 0, 2]))`

is basically the input series is it not?

And the following line is basically my cell declaration? 
`output_seqs, states = tf.nn.static_rnn(basic_cell, X_seqs, dtype=tf.float32)`

Comment: so, my placeholder is already defined as batchY and batchX 

`batchX_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, truncated_backprop_length])
batchY_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, truncated_backprop_length])`

and then I have my column unpacks

`labels_series = tf.unstack(batchY_placeholder, axis=1)
inputs_series = tf.split(1, truncated_backprop_length, batchX_placeholder)`

forward pass

`cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
states_series, current_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, inputs_series, init_state)`

Comment: @Glennismade please update your question. It's really hard to read the code from the comments

Comment: sorry, updated the question with the new information. Cheers

Comment: @Maim, OMG, thank you. I'm an idiot. haha cheers. that seemed to solve the issue.

I still have some other stuff to resolve, but this was driving me nuts. Thank you so much.

Comment: As you seem to be the Tensorflow guy, and Idea what this is referring to? 

ValueError: Only call `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)

I'm guessing I have to initialise the Logits and the Labels to something?

Comment: @Glennismade can you make another question and provide the details?

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense.